# How to make a third party obj thread safe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I want to use a third module in python like this :

```
import some_module

class MyService():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_module_obj = some_module.some_obj()

    def run(self,some_parameter):
        self.some_module_obj.some_attritude(some_parameter)
```

I know that `some_module.some_obj` and its method `some_attritude` is not thread safe , My question is how to make `MyService` thread safe ?

update 1:

I see Artiom Kozyrev's code , Is the code below right ?

```
import some_module
import threading
GLOBAL_LOCK = threading.Lock()

class Singleton(type):

    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            with GLOBAL_LOCK:
                if cls not in cls._instances:
                    cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(
                        *args, **kwargs
                    )
        return cls._instances[cls]

class MyService(metaclass=Singleton):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_module_obj = some_module.some_obj()
        self.rlock = threading.RLock()

    def run(self,some_parameter):
        result = None
        with self.rlock:
            result = self.some_module_obj.some_attritude(some_parameter)
        return result
```

Comment: In what ways specifically are `some_obj` and `some_attribute` not thread safe?  Do you really need all invocations of `run` across all threads to share a single `some_obj`, or could you have one per `run`, or one per thread?  Is it acceptable to simply use a lock around that entire method call, or does that defeat the purpose of making `MyService` multithreaded?

Comment: I use ```MyService``` in a grpc project . Because instantiating ```MyService``` obj spends 5 seconds , I can't instantiate ```MyService``` in every thread . Could you please give an example code in answer ?